# JQuery Widget, losing reference to "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

**Note**: the code looks long but its simple psuedo code for demo purpose.  Don't flee!

I have written a widget that listens for key presses.  When the `onKeyDown` event is fired the reference to `this` is lost.   So I set a scoped variable called `self` to reference the widget.  `self` is initalised when the widget is created.

This works but I'm not sure this is the right approach.  I think the solution here is to do with a proxy? perhaps the `self` variable is already acting as a proxy?  anyone want to shed some light on whats happening?

```
(function($)
{   
    var vendorPrefix = Modernizr.prefixed("transform");
    var self;

    $.widget("ui.myWidget", {

        _create: function()
        {  
            self = this;            
            //Do some widget stuff  
            document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown, false)
            return this;
        },

        exampleFn: function()
        {
        },

        onKeyDown: function(event)
        {
            // this now refers to "document" and not the widget             
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case 37: 
                    self.exampleFn();
                    break;
                case 39:
                    self.exampleFn();
                    break;
            }
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Using `self = this` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) if you'd like to get rid of the `self` variable:

```
onKeyDown: $.proxy(function(event)
{
    // this now refers to "document" and not the widget             
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case 37: 
            this.exampleFn();
            break;
        case 39:
            this.exampleFn();
            break;
    }
}, this)
```

Anyway, what's happening is that `this` in a function refers to that function. So `this` in `onKeyDown` is `onKeyDown` function. If you use a proxy like I did above, `this` in `onKeyDown` will become a reference to the parent function.

More on `this` behavior in JavaScript: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: Hi Pawel, this is what I was thinking off. I'm a little unsure as to whether I have successfully scoped "self" or not, or have I created a global?  I'm a little conflicted about what to do.  "this" should really refer to the event, because thats the expected behaviour, at the same time, I am trying to constrain the event to within the widget...

Comment: I couldn't get you application of proxy to work so I used this "document.addEventListener('keydown', $.proxy(this.onKeyDown, this), false);"

Comment: I think that your approach with the `self` variable is also OK, that variable won't be available outside of the function in which it is declared. I often do it that way - it really depends on what I need. But I am not a so called JavaScript ninja. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the "this" keyword refers to the object where the event is attached.

Using the self tip is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by proxy as there's no such thing in javascript, but no, it's not  the right way of doing it as you've essentially created a global variable.

For instance, if the widget were initialized multiple times you would probably see some really weird behaviour depending on your code.

Get rid of the global `var self` and move it to above the `_create` method inside the object declaration so it's a private variable to that object.

Comment: Is `var self` global in the scope of that function?

Comment: The "proxy" concept may refer to the behaviour that `$.proxy` exhibits.

Comment: @MalSu - is self global?  I thought I had scoped it within the function?